# converting polygon data points (shapefile) into point datapoints (another shapefile), using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am creating my own dataset for landuse classification.
I have four different shapefiles for 4 different categories, forest, water, park and buildings.
All these shapefiles contain polygon geometries of various sizes of respective categories.

I want to create shapefile of each category which contains points instead of polygons. 
For example, my forest shapefile contains 10 polygons and i want to create another shapefile for the forest, which will contain 100 or more points. Obviously these points should lie within these polygons.

I don't want to manually select the points which will be quite cumbersome given the no of shapes and points.

I would like to know any  automatic method using QGIS.

Comment: Did you have a look at the "Random point inside polygons", "point along geometry", or "extract vertices" tool in the processing toolbox , if yes could you elaborate on how they don't fit your need ?

Comment: No, I was not aware about these tools. They sounds like exactly what I need. I will check them and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, "random point inside geometry" tool in QGIS did the work. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by J,R. in comments, 
"**random point inside geometry**" tool in the processing toolbox of **QGIS** did the work.

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to accept it before. May be it take some hours before one can do that.